# Converting invalid json to json or javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have below string which doesn't have quotes around keys and values. How can I convert it to json?

```
"{1000:{FUEL LINE: NR, FUEL LEVEL: I, THROTTLE OPERATION: NR, CHOKE OPERATION: NR, AIR CLEANER: NR, CRANKCASE BREATHER:
NR , SPARK PLUG: NR, VALVE CLEARANCE: I, ENGINE OIL: R, ENGINE OIL STRAINER SCREEN: C, SUSPENSION: I, NUTS, BOLTS FASTENERS: I, WHEEL/TYRES: I, STEERING HEAD BEARINGS: NR}
}"
```

I tried below code but not working.
`JSON.parse(JSON.string(data))['100']` 
It's not working giving me 100th element, still treating it as string.

Comment: that is not a valid json

Comment: You will probably have to write your own parser for this, or do some research to see if you can find one that can do the job. (Maybe there are pseudo-JSON parsers with a build-in “fault tolerance” for stuff like this.) Or you complain to whoever gave you this mess in the first place …

Comment: @misorude What if id regex replace? I could do replacing `{` with `"{"`. But I don't know if this would work.

Comment: What is the correct syntax of `SUSPENSION: NR, NUTS, BOLTS FASTENERS: I`? `"suspension": ["nr", "nuts", "bolts"], "fasteners": "I"` or `"suspension": "nr", "nuts/bolts fasteners": "I"` or `"suspension": "nr", "nuts/bolts": null, "fasteners": "I"` 
 or something else?

Comment: sorry guys, it's foolish. Actually I thought keys  and values are uniform separated by `:`. It can't be converted. Anyhow If I manage to do so by replacing characters. It will break because pattern might differ.

Comment: @nickzoum obviously it should be `"suspension": "nr, nuts/bolts", "fasteners: "I"`. Like others

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON has some major issues - for example:

> SUSPENSION: NR, NUTS, BOLTS FASTENERS: I, WHEEL/TYRES: NR, STEERING
>   HEAD BEARINGS: I

Where does the key / value start and end?
I think it should be something like this:

> SUSPENSION: [NR, NUTS, BOLTS], FASTENERS: I, WHEEL/TYRES: [NR, STEERING,
>   HEAD], BEARINGS: I

When you repaired the String logically you can add the missing `'` with something like: 
`data.replace(/[\w\d]+/gi, "'$&'")`

But in your case I think this regex would do a better job:

`data.replace(/((\w|\d|\/)+[\s\w\d\/]*)+/gi, "'$&'")`

In your current data string it would result in:

```
    "{'1000':{'FUEL LINE': 'NR', 'FUEL LEVEL': 'I', 'THROTTLE OPERATION': 'NR', 'CHOKE OPERATION': 'NR', 'AIR CLEANER': 'NR', 'CRANKCASE BREATHER':'NR ', 'SPARK PLUG': 'NR', 'VALVE CLEARANCE': 'I', 'ENGINE OIL': 'R', 'ENGINE OIL STRAINER SCREEN': 'C', 'ENGINE IDLE SPEED': 'I', 
'SECONDARYAIR SUPPLY SYSTEM': 'NR', 'SECONDARY AIR SUPPLY SYSTEM AIR CLEANER': 'NR ', 'DRIVE BELT': 'NR', 'FINAL DRIVE OIL': 'NR', 'BRAKE SHOESWEAR': 'NR', 'BRAKE SYSTEM': 'I', 'BRAKE LOCK OPERATION': 'I', 'BATTERY VOLTAGE': 'I', 'HEAD LIGHT AIM': 'NR', 'LIGHTS/HORN': 'NR', 'CLUTCHSHOES WEAR': 'NR', 'SUSPENSION': 'NR', 'NUTS', 'BOLTS FASTENERS': 'I', 'WHEEL/TYRES': 'NR', 'STEERING HEAD BEARINGS': 'I'},
'4000':{'FUEL LINE': 'I', 'FUEL LEVEL': 'I', 'THROTTLE OPERATION': 'I', 'CHOKE OPERATION': 'I', 'AIR CLEANER': 'NR', 'CRANKCASE BREATHER': 'C','SPARK PLUG': 'I', 'VALVE CLEARANCE': 'I', 'ENGINE OIL': 'R', 'ENGINE OIL STRAINER SCREEN': 'NR', 'ENGINE IDLE SPEED': 'I', 'SECONDARY AIRSUPPLY SYSTEM': 'NR', 'SECONDARY AIR SUPPLY SYSTEM AIR CLEANER': 'NR ', 'DRIVE BELT': 'NR', 'FINAL DRIVE OIL': 'NR', 'BRAKE SHOES WEAR':'I', 
'BRAKE SYSTEM': 'I', 'BRAKE LOCK OPERATION': 'I', 'BATTERY VOLTAGE': 'I', 'HEAD LIGHT AIM': 'I', 'LIGHTS/HORN': 'I', 'CLUTCH SHOES WEAR':'NR', 'SUSPENSION': 'I', 'NUTS', 'BOLTS FASTENERS': 'NR', 'WHEEL/TYRES': 'I', 'STEERING HEAD BEARINGS': 'NR'},'8000':{'FUEL LINE': 'I', 'FUEL LEVEL': 'I', 'THROTTLE OPERATION': 'I', 'CHOKE OPERATION': 'I', 'AIR CLEANER': 'NR', 'CRANKCASE BREATHER': 'C','SPARK PLUG': 'R', 'VALVE CLEARANCE': 'I', 'ENGINE OIL': 'R', 'ENGINE OIL STRAINER SCREEN': 'NR', 'ENGINE IDLE SPEED': 'I', 'SECONDARY AIRSUPPLY SYSTEM': 'NR', 'SECONDARY AIR SUPPLY SYSTEM AIR CLEANER': 'NR ', 'DRIVE BELT': 'I', 'FINAL DRIVE OIL': 'NR', 'BRAKE SHOES WEAR':'I', 'BRAKE SYSTEM': 'I', 'BRAKE LOCK OPERATION': 'I', 'BATTERY VOLTAGE': 'I', 'HEAD LIGHT AIM': 'I', 'LIGHTS/HORN': 'I', 'CLUTCH SHOES WEAR':'I', 'SUSPENSION': 'I', 'NUTS', 'BOLTS FASTENERS': 'I', 'WHEEL/TYRES': 'I', 'STEERING HEAD BEARINGS': 'NR'}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

- You first need to manage the errors i.e. `SUSPENSION: NR, NUTS, BOLTS FASTENERS: I`. (You need to decide what the correct format is, I've just removed it altogether).
- Then you need to add quotes before and after every one of these characters (`{ : ,`) that is followed by a letter or number.
- Finally remove the new lines.
- The text is now ready for parsing.

```js
var text = `{1000:{FUEL LINE: NR, FUEL LEVEL: I, THROTTLE OPERATION: NR, CHOKE OPERATION: NR, AIR CLEANER: NR, CRANKCASE BREATHER:
    NR , SPARK PLUG: NR, VALVE CLEARANCE: I, ENGINE OIL: R, ENGINE OIL STRAINER SCREEN: C, ENGINE IDLE SPEED: I, SECONDARY
    AIR SUPPLY SYSTEM: NR, SECONDARY AIR SUPPLY SYSTEM AIR CLEANER: NR , DRIVE BELT: NR, FINAL DRIVE OIL: NR, BRAKE SHOES
    WEAR: NR, BRAKE SYSTEM: I, BRAKE LOCK OPERATION: I, BATTERY VOLTAGE: I, HEAD LIGHT AIM: NR, LIGHTS/HORN: NR, CLUTCH
    SHOES WEAR: NR, SUSPENSION: NR, NUTS, BOLTS FASTENERS: I, WHEEL/TYRES: NR, STEERING HEAD BEARINGS: I},
    4000:{FUEL LINE: I, FUEL LEVEL: I, THROTTLE OPERATION: I, CHOKE OPERATION: I, AIR CLEANER: NR, CRANKCASE BREATHER: C,
    SPARK PLUG: I, VALVE CLEARANCE: I, ENGINE OIL: R, ENGINE OIL STRAINER SCREEN: NR, ENGINE IDLE SPEED: I, SECONDARY AIR
    SUPPLY SYSTEM: NR, SECONDARY AIR SUPPLY SYSTEM AIR CLEANER: NR , DRIVE BELT: NR, FINAL DRIVE OIL: NR, BRAKE SHOES WEAR:
    I, BRAKE SYSTEM: I, BRAKE LOCK OPERATION: I, BATTERY VOLTAGE: I, HEAD LIGHT AIM: I, LIGHTS/HORN: I, CLUTCH SHOES WEAR:
    NR, SUSPENSION: I, NUTS, BOLTS FASTENERS: NR, WHEEL/TYRES: I, STEERING HEAD BEARINGS: NR},
    8000:{FUEL LINE: I, FUEL LEVEL: I, THROTTLE OPERATION: I, CHOKE OPERATION: I, AIR CLEANER: NR, CRANKCASE BREATHER: C,
    SPARK PLUG: R, VALVE CLEARANCE: I, ENGINE OIL: R, ENGINE OIL STRAINER SCREEN: NR, ENGINE IDLE SPEED: I, SECONDARY AIR
    SUPPLY SYSTEM: NR, SECONDARY AIR SUPPLY SYSTEM AIR CLEANER: NR , DRIVE BELT: I, FINAL DRIVE OIL: NR, BRAKE SHOES WEAR:
    I, BRAKE SYSTEM: I, BRAKE LOCK OPERATION: I, BATTERY VOLTAGE: I, HEAD LIGHT AIM: I, LIGHTS/HORN: I, CLUTCH SHOES WEAR:
    I, SUSPENSION: I, NUTS, BOLTS FASTENERS: I, WHEEL/TYRES: I, STEERING HEAD BEARINGS: NR}
    }`.replace(/(NUTS\,\s*BOLTS)/g, "")
  .replace(/(\{|\,|\:)\s*(\w|\d)/g, "$1\"$2").replace(/(\w|\d)\s*(\}|\,|:)/g, "$1\"$2").replace(/\n|\r/g, "");

console.log(JSON.parse(text));
```